# www.mysite.com/ and www.mysite.com/index.html dupe content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I am running a static web site via Apache. So, if you visit http://www.mysite.com/products, http://www.mysite.com/products/, and http://www.mysite.com/products/index.html, you see the same thing.

Will this result in dupe content, from Google's perspective? Should I htaccess redirect http://www.mysite.com/products and http://www.mysite.com/products/ to http://www.mysite.com/products/index.html?

I have DirectoryIndex set to index.html. Further, I have the following meta tags in place:

On the home page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
```

On the products page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/products" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done with defining canonicals is correct Chad. Although if the duplicate pages don't need to be accessed independently of the main page, I myself always try to implement 301 redirects in the 1st instance. 301 redirects are the preferred choice, as canonicals tags are a hint, not an absolute directive.

If you are actively linking to any of these 'duplicate pages' (such as a home link linking to `www.example.com/index.html`, rather than the root `www.example.com/`) you should update your internal linking to reflect your canonical URLs where possible.

Also make sure any sitemap.xml files only include the main 'canonical' URLs. Duplicate pages, or any pages redirected, canonicaled or blocked else where should not be included in sitemap.xml files.